# Disable Number of Files Copied in Copy Command

Tags: batch-file, copy

How do I remove the prompt of copy command when it's done copying?
/y only removes the prompt of overwriting a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>nul` removes stdout messages but allows error messages to appear.

```
copy "c:\file.txt" "d:\folder" >nul
```

If you use `>nul 2>&1` then all messages will be removed (sent to the nul device).

Comment: Thanks!
Where does 2>&1 came from?

Comment: It sends the `number 2` STDERR (standard error) stream to the same place that the `number 1` STDOUT (standard out) stream is going.  In the example above `STDOUT` is going to `NUL` first so `STDERR` will then go to `NUL` as well. STDOUT messages are the usual information messages from a console program.